# What do you call something that determines the world

Tags: metaphysics, cosmology

A computer and software determines a simulation, however, the world we don't know if it's a simulation or not, so let's assume that it's not a simulation, then what do you call something that determines reality similarly to a computer and software determining what we see in a simulation. Is there a word for this?

Comment: Holographic hypotheses (like AdS / CFT) might give you an answer, but mainstream physics treats those as merely useful tools for now (mathematical shortcuts), not as a proper description of reality.

Comment: Define reality. If reality is everything that is, then obviously reality determines itself (whatever that means...) because nothing outside of it can fill this role. And imagining something that is not part of reality opens a whole other can of worms (so what is it then? something not real ?). A relevant question can't be formulated with ill defined terms.

Comment: i think i see what you are asking, whethere there is a word or concept analagous to the computer running a simulation - reality - if reality is not a simulation. but i think that if reality is not a simulation, then - theism aside - reality is all there is.

Comment: [Sufficient cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_sufficient_reason) of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something that is independent of everything else that exists, then it would be "fundmental"

> The notion of fundamentality, as it is used in metaphysics, aims to
> capture the idea that there is something basic or primitive in the
> world. This metaphysical notion is related to the vernacular use of
> “fundamental”, but philosophers have also put forward various
> technical definitions of the notion. Among the most influential of
> these is the definition of absolute fundamentality in terms of
> ontological independence or ungroundednes

---

You might want to look into 'grounding', if that's the kind of determination you mean, and whether there is an **universal ground** (which is usually, but not always, religious).

> [some] claims are [grounding](https://%20https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/grounding/) claims, where grounding is understood to be a
> form of constitutive (as opposed to causal or probabilistic)
> determination or explanation.

Or you might be asking about a **first cause**. If by "determine" you don't mean anything active, then why not Plotinus's

> The One, being beyond all attributes including being and non-being, is
> the source of the world—but not through any act of creation, willful
> or otherwise, since activity cannot be ascribed to the unchangeable,
> immutable One

I don't know of one word that covers all these different ways of thinking about what you might be asking.